# can a templated member function implement two base classes's virtual functions?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

ive got an odd scenario here... ive got a class that does multiple inheritance of a templated base class, that i would like to implement in my final derived class with a single templated implementation

templated base :

```
//simple class with a pure virtual function DoFoo()
template <typename T> 
struct foo
{
    virtual T DoFoo() = 0;
};
```

base2:

```
//a simple class that inherits from foo, but does not implemented DoFoo()
struct bar {};
struct base2 : public foo<bar> 
{

};
```

final derived class:

```
//a class that inherits from base2, and foo<bar2>, 
//that needs an implementation of DoFoo for both bar and bar2 types. 
struct bar2{};
struct final : public base2, public foo<bar2> 
{
     template <T>
     T DoFoo(){ return T();}

};
```

i would expect to see that the compiler would generate the two virtual functions that the struct final must implement, a version of DoFoo for both bar and bar2.. The templated function, if the compiler is able to see it, should be able to generate a templated function that matches both virtual function prototypes.

However, it appears as though the compiler believes that the DoFoo() functions, for bar and bar2 are missing, barfing with a " because the following virtual functions are pure within " error.

am i missing something with regards to syntax? or is this an impossible situation that ive run into with regards to inheritance & templates? why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, it appears as though the compiler believes that the DoFoo() functions, for bar and bar2 are missing

It's correct.  `foo::DoFoo` names a `foo` member function. `final::DoFoo` names a member template, not a member function.  `final::DoFoo<int>` does name a member function whose definition is generated by instantiating that template, but the member function's name is `final::DoFoo<int>` -- the angle brackets at that point are no more than part of how it's spelled.

Comment: So dofoo<int> could never match with foo::dofoo()'s function signature? I guess because the generated function types are template parametrized and the virtual function is not?

Comment: @MichaelXu that's correct, though I'd say it as "because the generated function names include the template arguments".

Comment: ok, after a bit of sleep, i think it makes more sense.. the template in final is  a templated member function, whereas foo is a templated class with a member function. these are two different things and cannot get matched by the compiler